# Gmail api Thread List Snippet

Tags: python, gmail-api

I have been attempting to work with the GMail API and client libraries. I'm able to use the javascript node SDK to get a list of threads, but the snippet comes back as "".

```
client.gmail.users.threads.list({userId: "me"}).withAuthClient(auth_with_access_token).execute(function (err, response) {
            res.json({complete: response.threads})
        });
```

I then downloaded the python SDK and got a list of threads as well using the gmail api sample and noticed those have empty snippets as well.

```
for thread in threads['threads']:
    print 'Thread: %s' % (thread)
```

> Thread ID: {u'snippet': u'', u'id': u'146fccb21d960498', u'historyId':
>   u'7177452'}

When I request the thread via the get thread method I do get a snippet, though, it's only missing on the thread list.

Is there additional details I need to include in the request to get the snippet?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like an API problem to me. I am also not getting the snippets in JAVA API. So I tried the same thing on "Oauth2.0 playground" but no snippets there either.

Comment: Not yet, just ran the canned python sample and still get a "" snippet.

Comment: Still the same, maybe snippet on the list of threads won't be supported? Anyone from google care to chime in, I thought this was monitored?

Comment: I have tried contacting google through feedbacks and G+ but never got a response. And  haven't seen any google person on any gmail-api threads.

Comment: This continues, makes me think it's not something they care to fix? Too bad, seems like a bit of context from the thread would significantly cut down on platform traffic, but we'll just start eagerly downloading threads I guess.

Comment: This is still an issue as of today. It would be great to be able to display a thread with an identifier other than the id but it seems like a [batch request](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch) may be the most efficient solution for now.

Comment: This issue still persist... Does any one have updates or any patch regarding this...

Answer (score 3):

I can grab message snippets fine by using this code, following authentication:

```
message = service.users().messages().get(userId=user_id, id=msg_id, format='raw').execute()
print 'Message snippet: %s' % message['snippet']
```

This is obviously pulling a snippet for a particular message, but the principle remains.

Try this out and it should work, if not comment on this answer and I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks, yes I can get them for an individual message as well. Was really hoping to have the snippet on the list, much less http traffic and faster for the user.

Comment: What do you mean by snippet of the list? This might just be me being dense, but I don't think you can get a snippet of a list?

Comment: Currently the threads.list method does not include snippets, so to your question, no there are no details to include to get the snippet from threads.list.

This is a known issue within Google, and options of including the snippet in threads.list or removing the field totally are currently being considered by Gmail API team. Keep checking the docs for updates to this issue.

Comment: @kroikie That's what I thought, trying to get Trtanqy to clarify the question so that he understands why I can't help/have answered the way I have :p